# measure-theory study of $F(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(\mathbf{1}_{Q_k}(x,y)-\mathbf{1}_{V_k}(x,y))$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let's denote:

$$Q_k := (k,k+1)\times(k,k+1)$$
$$V_k :=(k,k+1)\times(-2k,-k)$$

let be 
$$F(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(\mathbf{1}_{Q_k}(x,y)-\mathbf{1}_{V_k}(x,y))$$

Verify that $F$ is measurable and limited in $\mathbb{R^2}$ showing a lower and upper bound.

Denoted 
$H_+ := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : y>0\} $
$H_- := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : y<0\} $,
establish whether $F\in L^1(H_+)$ and whether $ F\in L^1(H_-)$

Calculate, if it exist, $\int_{R^2} F(x,y)dxdy$

Comment: I know I should write my way of reasing, but for lack of time i'll add it later. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer given by a friend of mine on the main problem: the integration on $H_+$ or $H_-$

Let's consider $H_+$

$$\int_{H_+} F(x,y)dm = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{Q_k} F(x,y)dm \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$

Now, because $x \in (k,k+1)$,

$$ k < x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  k^2 < x^2 \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ \ 2k^2<x^2 + y^2 \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} < \frac{1}{2k^2}$$

So we can conclude

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k^2} < \infty$$