# Question on integration: $\int_{k}^{k+1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let consider $k \in \mathbb{N}$, I'm trying to solve this integral, or better to prove that this integral exists:
$$\int_{k}^{k+1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$

This question is related to this one, [measure-theory study of $F(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(\mathbf{1}_{Q_k}(x,y)-\mathbf{1}_{V_k}(x,y))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3344368)
because I'm trying to show $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ is integrable on every $Q_k$.

Let me show how I begin:

$$\int_{k}^{k+1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy = \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{y}\Big[\arctan\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big)\Big]^{k+1}_{k}dy = \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{y}\Big[\arctan\Big(\frac{k+1}{y}\Big)-\arctan\Big(\frac{k}{y}\Big)\Big] dy$$

Now, because $y\in[k,k+1]$, we have  $\ \pi/2 \geq \arctan\Big(\frac{k+1}{y}\Big) \geq \pi/4$ and simmetrically $0 \le \arctan\Big(\frac{k+1}{y}\Big) \le \pi/4$.

Beacuse of this I can say $\arctan\Big(\frac{k+1}{y}\Big)-\arctan\Big(\frac{k}{y}\Big)\le \pi/4$ and I can conclude:

$$\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{y}\Big[\arctan\Big(\frac{k+1}{y}\Big)-\arctan\Big(\frac{k}{y}\Big)\Big] dy \le \frac{\pi}{4}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{y} 
 = \frac{\pi}{4}\log\Big(\frac{k+1}{k}\Big) < \infty$$

Comment: Please let me know what do you think about

Comment: To prove it converges you can just bound $1/(x^2+y^2)$ by constants there is no need to perform any integration first.

Comment: I think the given integral diverges since we will have $1-\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)}$ in the denominator inside the arctangent of an integral comes later in the steps. I hope no mistakes I have done.

Comment: And what's wrong on what I've answered and other comments?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari What does that to do with anything? $\arctan$ is a bounded function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\overline{Q_k}$ is compact and $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous on $\overline{Q_k}$ , hence $f$ is integrable over $\overline{Q_k}$.

Thus $f$ is integrable over $Q_k.$

Comment: Okay, but if I ask you an estimastion of that integral?